# Сравнить массивы С++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Вводятся два массива. Как определить, можно ли из символов первого массива создать строку идентичную второму массиву?
Cложность в том что первый массив может иметь несколько одинаковых символов и при сортировке и сравнении массивов код работает неверно, по идее из символов первого массива "aboba" можно создать строку идентичную второму массиву "abob", но программа говорит что нельзя из за того что в первом массиве два символа 'a'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

bool isPermutation(char* str1, char* str2, int size)
{
    std::sort(str1, str1 + size);
    std::sort(str2, str2 + size);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (str1[i] != str2[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}


int main()
{
    const int size = 256;
    char* str1 = new char[size];
    char* str2 = new char[size];
    std::cin >> str1 >> str2;
    std::cout << isPermutation(str1, str2, 256);
    delete[] str1;
    delete[] str2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: и что вы сделали для решения данной задачи? какие у вас сложности возникли?

Comment: сложность в том что первый массив может иметь несколько одинаковых символов и при сортировке и сравнении массивов код работает неверно, по идее из символов первого массива "aboba" можно создать строку идентичную второму массиву "abob", но программа говорит что нельзя из за того что в первом массиве два символа 'a'

Comment: добавьте данную инфу в сам вопрос, нажав [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1342358/edit). Очень бы помогло иметь не только ваш код, но и входные и ожидаемые на выходе данные

Comment: @балалайка Для того что бы получить хоть какие то ответы, нужно правильно составлять вопросы и обязательно прикладывать свой код! Так что приложите свои наработки, вам помогут

Answer (score 1):

можно попробовать такой алгоритм (если я правильно понял задачу)

1. пройтись по 1 массиву и подсчитать какие символы сколько раз встречаются, например заполнив структуру

   ```
    std::map<char, int>
   ```
2. пройтись по второму массиву и выполнить обратную операцию, т.е. уменьшать счетчик для найденных символов, если счётчик упал до -1, то значит нельзя используя массив 1 получить массив 2

Пример:

"aboba" -> "abob"

```
a: 2
b: 2
o: 1
```

[a]bob

```
a: 1
b: 2
o: 1
```

a[b]ob

```
a: 1
b: 1
o: 1
```

ab[o]b

```
a: 1
b: 1
0: 0
```

abo[b]

```
a: 1
b: 0
0: 0
```

нигде -1 не возникло - значит все ок

Comment: если не сложно, не могли бы реализовать это в коде?

Comment: не понял, т.е. реализовать задачу в коде? А где у вас сложности там?

Comment: ну вы просто знаете как работает эта функция, а я нет, было бы проще если бы вы вписали это всё в код, если вам не сложно

Comment: но разве это не обучающая задача цель которой научить некоторому алгоритмическому подходу, выучить стандартную библиотеку c++ и т.д.?
весь код там строчек на 5 для всей задачи (без учета скобок)

Comment: Используйте не `map`, а массив из 256 `char`...

Comment: @Zhihar просто я не понимаю как это всё вписать в код, напишите вы пожалуйста